# Align equations in 2 columns (centered + right)

Tags: latex

I want to align a couple of equations after the following schematic:

[image: allignment schematic]

I would prefer to use the equation-function, if possible, to make the code reusable, without changing the numbering of the equations by hand.

I tried a couple of things, but function-nesting seems to be a problem the way I try it.

Codeblock1:

```
\begin{align*}
  \begin{equation}\label{equ_bat_change1}
    Bat_{t} &= Bat_{t - 1} + Bat_{in, t} - Bat_{out,t} &&t \in [1;96] 
  \end{equation}\label{equ_bat_change1}
  \begin{equation}\label{equ_bat_change2}
    Bat_{0} &= 0 
  \end{equation}\label{equ_bat_change2}
  \begin{equation}\label{equ_bat_change3}
    BatCtrl_{t}(Bat_{in,t}) &= P_{in,t} - P_{out,t} + PV_{t} - Usage_{t} && \forall t \in T
  \end{equation}\label{equ_bat_change3}
\end{align*}
```

Codeblock2:

```
\begin{equation}\label{equ_bat_change}
  \begin{aligned}[t]
    Bat_{t} = Bat_{t - 1} + Bat_{in, t} - Bat_{out,t} \begin{right}t \in [1;96] \end{}
  \end{aligned}[t]
\end{equation}\label{equ_bat_change}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because should have been migrated to tex.stackexchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for using `align` is incorrect and should not include something like an `equation`. Here's how you can achieve your goal:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Bat}{\mathrm{Bat}}
\newcommand{\BatCtrl}{\mathrm{BatCtrl}}
\newcommand{\IN}{\mathrm{in}}
\newcommand{\OUT}{\mathrm{out}}

\begin{document}

See \eqref{eqn:two}.
\begin{align}
  \Bat_t &= \Bat_{t - 1} + \Bat_{\IN, t} - \Bat_{\OUT, t} && t \in [1;96] \\
  \Bat_0 &= 0 \label{eqn:two} \\
  \BatCtrl_t(\Bat_{\IN, t}) &= P_{\IN, t} - P_{\OUT, t} + PV_t - \text{Usage}_t && \forall t \in T
\end{align}

\end{document}
```